# Sharing property beetween tabBarViewController and his child controllers (items)

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Need to share property from tabBarViewController to child controllers(items)
Property must change with the help of child controllers

All classes are custom.

Example 
 interface of my class for UITabBarController

@interface TabBarVC : UITabBarController

@property (retain, nonatomic)  NSString *someProperty;

@end

interface of child view controller

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@end

THX for help!

Answer (score 0):

They can't necessarily share the same property, but they can both have properties that point to the same object.